# I wrote a js code to execute in the webview of Android, but I found that it didn't execute, please give me some suggestions

Tags: javascript, android, webview

According to the following code, I wrote a js method. In the onPageFinished method of webview, I went to execute it, but it didn't achieve the effect I wanted. The value of media did not change.
this is my js code :

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
"var links = document.getElementsByTagName(\"link\");" +
"for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){" +
"var link = links[i];" +
"if(link.getAttribute(\"href\").indexOf(\"pad.css\") != -1) {" +
"link.setAttribute(\"media\",  \"(min-width:9999px)\");" +
"}" +
"if(link.getAttribute(\"href\").indexOf(\"phone.css\") != -1) {" +
"link.setAttribute(\"media\",  \"(max-width:9999px)\");" +
"}" +
"}" +
"})()");
```

and I am going to execute it in the onPageFinished method.

this is html code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../META-INF/css/pad.css" media="(min-width:600px)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../META-INF/css/phone.css" media="(max-width:600px)"/>
<title>info</title>
```

Comment: Please explain what does happen when you run it.  "Didn't work" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: @Archer This is webview running custom js, I can't see the log,

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews